# how i can use landscape in Navigation Component in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need see my screens by landscape in Navigation Component in android studio .
[this is Navigation Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qqBv.png)

[I want see this display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqMbg.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 8):

Just press the letter `O` (not zero) on the keyboard to turn your views.

Comment: Is this still supported? It always stays in portrait mode for me, even if I put all of my res files to layout-land folder.